# Cannot override with a stored property

Tags: swift, properties, overriding

I have a cell & associated model.
the cell has a select button, on tapping which I am de/selecting.
I have to keep a variable in the cell (in order to maintain de/selected states) 
in the cellForRowAtIndexpath, I am configuring the cell along with selected info.

My problem:- Since I have to maintain a variable in the cell, My idea was to have a stored property (var isSelected = false) in the cell. I tried the same, compiler asked me to override isSelected property (as it was already declared in UITableViewCell ), when I override got the error "Cannot override with a stored property 'isSelected'"

Can anybody explain to me why this error is thrown 
Note - I want to use the same name isSelected

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can I can't same variable name which declared in parent class and its private there.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "maintaining a variable in the cell"? Are you using a custom cell and keeping your variable there, or are you trying to define and keep your variable in the table view's data source methods, such as cellForRowAt?

Comment: Yes I am using a custom cell, to maintain multiple selections I need to have a variable - specify it's value from cellForRowAtIndexpath (so that I could update ui based on selected info)

Answer (score 2):

In a subclass a property can only be overridden with the same type

As `isSelected` is declared as read/write

```
var isSelected: Bool { get set }
```

you have to override it adding getter and setter

```
override var isSelected : Bool {
    get { return false }
    set { super.isSelected = newValue }
}
```

or with a setter which does nothing

```
override var isSelected : Bool {
    get { return false }
    set {}
}
```